# Handling state react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, state, setstate

This is my picker with a linechart(LChart) component.

```
<Picker selectedValue = {this.state.value}
          onValueChange = {this.onValueChange}
          >
          <Picker.Item value='' label='Select Device...' />
          {devices.map((s, i) => {
            return (<Picker.Item label={s} value={s} key={i}/>)
        })}
            </Picker>

        <LChart data={Fdata} title={"LineChart"}/>
```

I have an array of devices to feed into picker and with every onValuechange i want to show the linechart of respective device.
My onValueChange function:

```
onValueChange = async(value) => {
      this.setState({ value: value })
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      var Fdata = [];
      fetch('http://ec2-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3009/chart/unitID', {
        method: 'post',
        headers:{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
          unitID: value,
        }) })
      .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          responseJson.forEach(function (vol) {
            Fdata.push({
              value: vol.voltage,
              date: new Date(vol.time),
            });
          });
          if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({
                Fdata: Fdata,
            });
          }
        })
      }, 5000);
   }
```

my issue here is when i initially select a device from picker, the line chart shows up perfect and reloads according to my set interval.
But when i select a different device from the picker, the line chart started to toggle between first and second device data and same continues with 3 rd selection and so on.

I guess i am not handling the state properly.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You're not clearing the interval that is created.

Comment: @zero298 I just did this and it working fine
`
clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up the interval.  Right now, you just keep creating additional intervals that will ping the device.  One thing you could do is create a `useEffect` that will clear the interval after the selected device changes.  The example below uses a placeholder, but you should be able to see the general idea.

```js
const {useState, useEffect, Fragment} = React;

const Chart = ({deviceData}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {deviceData ? (
                <Fragment>
                    <div>Date fetched: {Date.now()}</div>
                    <pre><code>{JSON.stringify(deviceData, null, 4)}</code></pre>
                </Fragment>
            ) : (
                <p>Waiting for device</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const [selectedDevice, setSelectedDevice] = useState("");
    const [deviceAttrs, setDeviceAttrs] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!selectedDevice) return;
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${selectedDevice}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setDeviceAttrs(data));
        }, 5000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [selectedDevice]);

    const options = [1, 2, 3];

    return (
        <div>
            <select onChange={e => setSelectedDevice(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="">Please select a device</option>
                {options.map(option => (
                    <option key={option} value={option}>Device {option}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
            {selectedDevice ? (
                <Chart deviceData={deviceAttrs} />
            ) : (
                <div>Please select a device</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This is really helpful